# How do I add styling to column templates in Amcharts Treemap?

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I want to add margin-top styling to level 1 column template in Amcharts v4 TreeMap chart.

I have tried the following code but known of them works.

```
level0ColumnTemplate.column.marginTop   = 30;
level0ColumnTemplate.marginTop   = 30;
```

code Link:
http://jsfiddle.net/t42asecw/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to create vertical space between treemap columns. Can't do it on the actual series `columns.template` because those [try to occupy as much space as possible](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/treemap/#Area_division_methods). What you can try then, is to put a `paddingTop` on the `column`, e.g.:

```js
level1ColumnTemplate.column.paddingTop = 30;

// Don't forget to shift bullet, too
bullet1.dy = 15;
```

Fork of your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/notacouch/2vrk3e6s/

Or if you want even spacing on all sides, you can increase the `strokeWidth`, just be sure to increase `column.cornerRadius*` values as well (if your corners are rounded at all):

```js
level1ColumnTemplate.column.cornerRadius(30, 30, 30, 30)
level1ColumnTemplate.strokeWidth = 30;
```